Console.log doesnt output logs when tests are run using "Playwright Test for VS Code"
When I run playwright tests, written in Typescript, the logs are not output on the console.
I have console.log statements which do output fine when I debug the tests and are shown under "Debug Console" tab. However, when I run the tests, they don't show the results in Output tab or under "Test Results" tab.
I went through a few posts and tried adding this under launch.json file, after creating launch.json file which wasn't there earlier but this didn't help:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/t.js",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}

I've also tried choosing different options under Output tab drop-down which by default had 'Tasks' set

Please add some more information. at least share your code.

I'm facing the same issue after Playwright framework update.
After some investigations I found that the reason is custom reporter setup in playwright.conf.ts file.
The only way that works for me right now is disabling custom reporter for local tests run from VS Code. I just commented reporter: section in config and saved as a local change so it won't affect test run on CI.
